# Remove comments once they have been addressed by editing the question?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes leave a comment to point out a small mistake in a question.  Should I delete my comment once the questioner has edited the question to fix the mistake?  After all, my comment will not make sense to new readers.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, yes, at least that's what I usually do (and has been what others generally do on the other stack sites)